# Is it possible to measure the distance with the mpu6050 from the starting point?

Tags: accelerometer, gyroscope, mpu6050

Is it possible to mark the distance with mpu6050 (e.g gy521) in centimeters or other values?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking only possible or not, then yes it is possible. 
For the orientation calculation you could search up madgwick mahogany approach.
it is open source and available in C code.

For counting the distance it has traveled I recommend this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9jXoG0QYIA&t=0s&list=LLDTSv_-wKSBdIkkDH_OZZYA&index=8)
. If you want to calculate it by integrating it from acceleration itself. It will produce lots of error. his video is a good one if you can implement a Kalman filter if you have gps available.

Comment: But apparently I do not understand the principle of the accelerometer. When I change the position of the sensor relative to its axis, the accelerometer readings change, although the sensor is stationary. I do not understand. After all, the accelerometer should change its readings when moving only

Comment: accelerometer is just a machine that read acceleration that is applied to it.
for stationary object I think it will read earth acceleration.
If you move it, it will read the acceleration when I starts to move, and when it starts slowing down.
accelerometer that read acceleration when it is stationary is good for getting the heading. When you know it is stationary, you can know where is down and up just by reading the accelerometer.

Comment: I tried to move the accelerometer and fix after that. The result is the same. It is impossible to measure linear acceleration, since the readings change simply when turning about the x and y axes. I do not see the possibility of filtering these readings. Tell me please, is it possible to use some other sensor to track linear movements relative to the x, y axes?

Comment: are you sure you are reading the accelerometer? not the gyroscope? if it is only reading when turned, seems like it is the gyroscope readings.